# Can't seem to get Future to run callback in Scala

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, future

(I've not included the imports so as not to clutter this question)

(This is the simplest possible Scala App (created using scala-minimal template on Typesafe Activator))

I'm trying to run a query against an Elasticsearch Server.

I've run the same code on **sbt console** and I can see the results alright.

However, when I run the following code, I see `"END"` (code after the callbacks) being printed, but neither the Success callback nor the Failure callback get run.

I'm a Scala noob, so maybe I'm doing something wrong here? **This code compiles.** (Just to let you know all the imports are there)

```
object Hello{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val client = ElasticClient.remote("vm-3bsa", 9300)

  val res:Future[SearchResponse] = client.execute{ search in "vulnerabilities/3bsa" query "css" }

  res onComplete{
    case Success(s) => println(s)
    case Failure(t) => println("An error has occured: " + t)
  }

  println("END")
  //EDIT start
  Await.result(res,10.seconds)
  //EDIT end
  }
}
```

**FINAL EDIT**

Instead of using `onComplete`, it works if I, instead, print result of the call to `Await.result`:

```
val await=Await.result(res,10.seconds)
println(await)
// results shown
```

Comment: The problem is that `onComplete` returns immediately, so `main` finishes before the `Future` completes, and thus the callback can't be called as the problem has already exited.

Comment: I've added a call to `Await` but I still don't see the results. See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thread will register your `onComplete`, `println("END")` and then exit, this makes the program terminate so therefore you never see your onComplete callback.

You can use `Await.result(future, timeout)` to block the main thread to keep it alive until the answer arrives. In a server context that would be a big no-no but in a small app like this it is not a problem blocking one thread.

Comment: I've added `Await.result(res,10.seconds)` after `println("END")` but I still don't see the results. Is this what I was meant to do? See my Edit.

Comment: And you are sure the job does not take more than 10 seconds? The return value from Await.result will be the same thing that your onComplete gets inside the success and if it is a failure the exception will be re-thrown.

Comment: For this example I am sure. I'm just trying to get this to work right now, I will make it better once I can get it to work.

Comment: Try printing the return value from Await.result and skip the onComplete part.

Comment: Oh... I can see it now! Thank you.